# Tk Inter Object Oriented Programming

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Hi I have been working on this project on making a Chemistry A level Quiz for Students. 
I have made a set of classes which correspond to each TK inter Frame. There are classes of questions that inherit from main question. 
I dont know why i am getting this error and why my code is not working:

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ammarhusain/Desktop/Computing Project/Ammar Chemistry Program 
FINAL.py", line 3376, in <module>
    quiz = Main()
  File "/Users/ammarhusain/Desktop/Computing Project/Ammar Chemistry Program FINAL.py", line 3360, in __init__
    frame = F(container, self)
  File "/Users/ammarhusain/Desktop/Computing Project/Ammar Chemistry Program FINAL.py", line 1167, in __init__
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,controller)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2583, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2138, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-use"
```

Main Code:

```
class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)



        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}


        for F in (STUDENTLOGINPAGE,STAFFLOGINPAGE,STARTPAGE,STAGE1,STAGE2,STAGE3,STAGE4,STAGE5,LEADERBOARDPAGE):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

            self.show_frame(STUDENTLOGINPAGE)
            if self.frames == []:
                print ("Error in loading program")
 #This class inherits from Tk class within module of Tk Inter
                 #This basically displays each page in turn from the List 

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise() 

quiz = Main()
quiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: @eyllanesc: Please don't quote-format tracebacks. It's not any more readable, and you're actively damaging important spacing information in the question source.

Comment: The error is coming from one of your page classes that you didn't post - I can't tell which one, but it appears to be at line 1167 (that's the last line in the traceback that refers to your source code, rather than the Python library).  You have an `__init__` that is passing along 3 parameters to the inherited `Frame.__init__`, even though only two positional parameters are meaningful there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `,controller` from this line:

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,controller)
```

`controller` is an argument that is unique to the subclass, and is not something that is supported in the base class.